# Google Spreadsheet Applying functions to unfilled rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheet that is filled from a Google Form, and I need to apply functions in some columns of each row that is not been filled (inserted).

When the user fills the form the data goes to the sheet but the functions shifted to the next row by itself, but I want to apply the function in the same row.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Is this Excel? Or Google Sheets? Can you provide an example; a screenshot perhaps? Please clarify your question by editing it.

Comment: No its Google Spreadsheet .. I want to add a screenshoot but it tells me that I need 10 reputation to add an image

Comment: Then post the link in the comments, I can add it to the question. Btw., you gain reputation by accepting answers solving your questions.

Comment: @Leviathan I have added the image please check !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use arrayformula so in N2 you would enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(J2:J),J2:J+M2:M,)
```

This causes the formula to run itself down the sheet only once there is a value in the cells your trying to add. This way it doesnt prevent new entries from being added